# My C++ attempt to convert std::vector<std::string> to JSON doesn't compile

Tags: c++, json, vector

I am trying to port a program I've written in JavaScript to C++ to make it faster. In that program, I dealt somewhat with JSONs. So, I tried to make a method for converting a vector of strings into JSON:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class std::vector<std::string> {
    public: std::string JSON();
};

std::string std::vector<std::string>::JSON() {
    std::string ret="[";
    if (this->size()==0) {
        ret+="]";
        return ret;
    }
    int currentSize=this->size();
    for (int i=0; i<currentSize; i++) {
        if (i!=currentSize-1)
            ret+="\""+this->operator[](i)+"\",";
        else
            ret+="\""+this->operator[](i)+"\"]";
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> fieldOfStrings({"Hello","world","!"});
    std::cout <<fieldOfStrings.JSON() <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However, it doesn't compile:

```
/home/teo.samarzija/Documents/AECforWebAssembly/AECforWebAssembly.cpp:5:12: error: too few template-parameter-lists
 class std::vector<std::string> {
            ^
/home/teo.samarzija/Documents/AECforWebAssembly/AECforWebAssembly.cpp:9:13: error: specializing member 'std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::JSON' requires 'template<>' syntax
 std::string std::vector<std::string>::JSON() {
```

What am I doing wrong? I am fairly new to C++.

Comment: What should `class std::vector<std::string>` mean? Make a free function that takes `std::vector<std::string>` parameter (by const-ref, probably).

Comment: Yeah you don't extend classes like that, especially not standard library ones. This is just not valid. (Refer to your C++ book's chapter on classes.) You should use a JSON parser library anyway, not roll you own.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Sorry, I come from JavaScript.

Comment: @FlatAssembler -- Don't use JavaScript or any other language as a model when writing C++ code.  If you continue down the path of trying to emulate JavaScript in C++, all you will have are syntax errors, or if not that, buggy, inefficient code, or programs that just look weird to a regular C++ programmer.

Comment: @FlatAssembler Doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the `class std::vector<std::string>` does not make sense. Second, a class is not necessary since you can just define a function similar to your member function that takes in `std::vector<std::string>` and return the json string.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string JSON(std::vector<std::string> str) {
    std::string ret="[";
    if (str.size()==0) {
        ret+="]";
        return ret;
    }
    int currentSize=str.size();
    for (int i=0; i<currentSize; i++) {
        if (i!=currentSize-1)
            ret+="\""+str[i]+"\",";
        else
            ret+="\""+str[i]+"\"]";
    }
    return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> fieldOfStrings({"Hello","world","!"});
    std::cout <<JSON(fieldOfStrings) <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above the easiest way is a free function.

```
std::string JSON(std::vector<std::string>& vec) {
    std::string ret="[";
    if (vec.size()==0) {
        ret+="]";
        return ret;
    }
    int currentSize=vec.size();
    for (int i=0; i<currentSize; i++) {
        if (i!=currentSize-1)
            ret+="\""+vec[i]+"\",";
        else
            ret+="\""+vec[i]+"\"]";
    }
    return ret;
}
```

And call it like

```
std::cout << JSON(fieldOfStrings) <<std::endl;
```